# JSTL: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, jstl

I am receiving the exception below when trying to access one of my JSPS (using tomcat 7.0.52)

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:56)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:445)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:117)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.generateTLDLocation(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:325)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.<init>(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:154)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:410)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:475)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1427)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:138)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:242)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:102)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:198)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:373)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:657)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:264)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1208)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:915)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:811)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:796)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
```

Yes I have seen several questions on the same topic, but none have seemed to resolve my issue. So in my JSP I have

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

In my Web XML I have

```
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
```

And in my Maven POM I have

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

In the list of my maven resources I have the jstl-1.2.jar and no standard.jar as some of the answers I've seen seem to suggest can confuse things.

**EDIT:** Ok I did read the answer below, but it did seem to be a copy and paste from bits of other answers I had read and didn't actually take in to account any of the information I had put in my question (for example /jsp WAS part of my URI)

Anyway I seem to have sorted it by removing the app completely from my server and re-adding it! I'm not sure why stopping the server and republishing it didn't seem to work, but never mind it's working!

Answer (score 0):

I think its about your pom conf and lib files.

Try this one by one

1.Add these to your POM.xml and delete your jstl. Save POM and right click the project Maven >> Update

```
<!-- Servlet -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

2.Delete jstl lib in your libraries.

3.Control Apache Tomcat do you have = ? servlet-api.jar ,jsp-api.jar